# Titanium Alloy - How to run procedure after screen created

Tags: google-maps, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to update the current location on map view. I get the current location in controller:

```
var updateCurrentLocation = function updateCurrentLocation(e){
Ti.API.info("Update current location on map");

$.map.setLocation({
    latitude: e.coords.latitude,
    longitude: e.coords.longitude,
    latitudeDelta: 1,
    longitudeDelta: 1
});
}
```

But the problem is that at this time the code run, the map view has not been created yet, so it cannot update the current location.
Can any one suggest some technique to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found there is a event call "complete" on the Map View. So, to do anything that you want to happen after the map loaded, in Map controller, use:

```
$.map.addEventListener('complete', function(e) {
   Ti.API.info("Map controller: on Map complete");
   $.trigger('complete', e); // Trigger event for other controller can listen too.
   // And you can do other logic here.
});
```

Reference from [Titanium Doc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Modules.Map.View-event-complete)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not creating the map in the same controller? If you are just place the code after the map code, but that is obvious so I will assume you have thought of that.

Why not set the coords to the current user coords when you create the Map?

Worst case scenario, you can use setTimer(, timer ms) to call a function after a set amount of time if you wanted to call the updateCurrentLocation function after 500 milliseconds. This is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

[starting up the map controller](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/testInClass/blob/master/app/controllers/PhotoDetail.js)

```
function showMap() {
    // create the new controller and pass in the
    // model object as an argument 'item'
    var ctrl = Alloy.createController('MapView', {
        'item' : args.item // <-- pass is information + coords for map
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        args.photoListTab.open(ctrl.mainWindow);
    }, 200);
}
```

[in map controller](https://github.com/aaronksaunders/testInClass/blob/master/app/controllers/MapView.js)

```
// get the photo object from the parameters
var coords = args.item.custom_fields.coordinates[0];
var locationString = args.item.custom_fields.location_address;

// create annotation
var annotation = Alloy.Globals.Map.createAnnotation({
  latitude : Number(coords[1]),
  longitude : Number(coords[0]),
  title : args.item.custom_fields.location_string,
  myid : args.item.id
});
```

complete solution here https://github.com/aaronksaunders/testInClass